# Which tool/implementation to use for WebSocket based communication?

Tags: asp.net, websocket, message-queue, nonblocking

I need a .Net based solution that be able to push notifications to its clients. Client could be a Windows application or can be a Web application.

The important thing is that I don't need an RPC based approach as we do not need any sort of IO blocking based architecture. I first went for SignalR but when I found that its RPC based, I changed my mind although its Hubs API based approach is very easy to use.

Primarily, I need a Message-Oriented mechanism that is not only light weight and which also is **non-blocking**, **low overhead**, and one that is **reliable**, as my application is based on evidence based data and so cannot afford to loose any sent message as much as possible. Message could be queued however if message processor is busy.

I have looked over the internet for other solutions like node.js, SuperWebSocket but I am confused and being a novice cannot ascertain what exactly and which solution/alternative I should go for.

I hope someone would guide me, keeping in view what is best for my scenario/requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SignalR does offer [PersistentConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.persistentconnection%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) functionality that is less involved than the [Hubs API](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server). However, I had to search quite hard to find the documentation on it - they're clearly pushing Hubs.

Alternative .NET options that I know of are [XSockets](http://xsockets.net) who offer a PubSub mechanism. They're actively developing their solution.

I'm not sure of any solutions that 100% guarantee message delivery so you may need to add your own acknowledgement messaging into the solution you choose.

Also see:

- [Fleck](https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck)
- [SuperWebSocket](http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/)
- [Alchemy WebSockets](http://alchemywebsockets.net/)

The best way to determine the one with the lowest overhead would be to write a simple app for each and measure memory and CPU usage, and also message latency.

Answer (score 0):

Question is subjective, but this is my recommendation: http://www.asp.net/signalr

Comment: I have mentioned about signalR but perhaps you haven't read my question fully, nor you have specified why I should use signalR. I also asked for non blocking, message oriented mechanism but signalR is RPC based.